# form grid reloding three times every leaverecord method

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

In SalesTable,ProjInvoiceJournal and some other forms when i leave a record all lines reloading again 3 times. I deleted salestable form from cust layer to see if standart version works smoothly but it doesnt.
Any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reloading'? Method `active` gets triggered only once after you've left the record.

Comment: refreshing all saleslines records in grid control.I mean refilling salesLineGrid control with salesline records one by one and then selects the record recently selected by users. And this process takes time depending on number of salesline records.

Comment: "refilling salesLineGrid control with salesline records 3 times" - I couldn't reproduce this issue in the SalesTable form.